# : colon is not a valid char in the targetNamespace cxf-codegen-plugin wsdl2java

Tags: web-services, namespaces, cxf, maven-plugin, wsdl2java

I want to use cxf and i am trying to generate a client stub from a provided WSDL by maven with cxf-codegen-plugin wsdl2java

Problem is the targetNamespace is named:

```
http://ip:port/ws/EndpointName.inbound.ws:companyName
```

and maven generate-sources phase fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.7.5:wsdl2java (generate-jaxb) on project: Execution generate-jaxb of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.7.5:wsdl2java failed: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: : is not a valid char in the targetNamespace -> [Help 1]
```

I believe the endpoint is developed using WebMethods. The company hosting this WS endpoint is telling me they have no control over the targetNamespace.

I tried remplacing

```
:companyName
```

by

```
/companyName
```

client stub generation goes fine but I get an error when I try to contact their server:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find service named {http://ip:port/ws/EndpointName.inbound.ws/companyName}WebServiceName in wsdl http://ip:port/ws/EndpointName.inbound.ws:companyName?WSDL
```

Any idea?
Should i switch to axis2 to be compatible with WebMethods?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, chienlou! Have you fixed this problem? Could you, please, share, how you did it, cause mentioned answer didn't help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you add -validate=none to the wsdl2java command, it would bypass that check.

Comment: Does not work for me using cxf-codegen-plugin, using "<extraarg>-validate=none</extraarg>". (under configuration/wsdlOptions/wsdlOption). Does that have to be passed differently? I have tried CXF-Versions 2.7.12 and 3.0.1..

Comment: You can check @oguzhankinik 's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
": is not a valid char in the targetNamespace"
```

resolved by [CXF-6527](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6527).

You should update your Apache CXF version to a newer version. Issue which has resolved that problem has Fix Version/s of: `3.1.3, 2.7.18, 3.0.7`